# How to pass env parameters to a Laravel Mix 6?

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, environment-variables, laravel-mix

Is there some way to pass parameters to the laravel mix via the command line and get them in the webpack.mix.js file? For example, I added the line frontend-dev, but I can't get the "foo" variable after running "yarn run frontend-dev".

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "development": "mix",
        "frontend-dev": "mix -- --env foo=frontend"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14"
    }
}
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

//console.log(process.env);
console.log(process.env.foo); //output: undefined
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it from the command line...

```
npm run development --foo=frontend
```

Then in webpack.mix.js, you can prefix your foo variable with `npm_config_`.

```
console.log(process.env.npm_config_foo);
```

Otherwise, if you want the value to come from your .env file, you may need to prefix your .env variable with `MIX_`, like `MIX_FOO_VARIABLE=frontend`.

And then, in webpack.mix.js, you can do the following.

```
console.log(process.env.MIX_FOO_VARIABLE);
```

Comment: This doesn't work when using the mix command: `$ mix --production --ieCompat=true
error: unknown option '--ieCompat=true'` and `$ mix --production -- --ieCompat=true
[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--ieCompat=true'`